# Move the 'Add new Item' button to the top of a specific webpart

Tags: 2010, jquery

I have a page with multiple web parts.

Now I'm trying to move the "add new item" button on top of a webpart after the web part title.

I did this using jQuery, using the unique web part I want, but after the migration from 2007 into 2010 some of the web part ID changed.

So eg if the web part id is 5 in SP 2010, for some old pages it may be 6.

So I tried adding both 5 and 6, but then again this is not a solution as it moves the button on other web parts.

Answer (score 1):

using the id is generally a bad idea, specially if you have a common script for multiple pages

from what I see, you have three options

- jack bauer: keep your script and fiddle around with your webparts (move them, close them, re enable them) hoping that at some point the ids will match what you need
- nikita: embed a specific script on each page and use the ids for that page, instead of a global script (CEWP?)
- sheldon cooper: create a proper script that looks for, perhaps .ms-wpheader and matches by titles of the webparts to do whatever

Comment: +1 for character answer